# datatables, initialisation code?

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to Initialisation code with index column (static number column) and hidden one or more coloumn using server-side processing in datatable plugin for jquery?

This is the condition :
I have two field in table(id,name) in database, but i want datatable show static number column and name column with one hidden coloumn for field id.

I use Index column (static number column), DataTables with hidden columns and server-side processing with pipelining data but return alert result said "DataTabels warning(tabel id ='example'): Requested unknown parameter '2' from the data source for row 0. I think it because i have three coloumn in DataTabel and server-site returning two field from table(id,name) in database.

Thank for helping.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried to employ solution called _Google_?

Answer (score 1):

Directly from DataTables homepage ([datatables.net](http://datatables.net)):

- [DataTables with hidden columns](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html):

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').dataTable( {
          "aoColumnDefs": [ 
              { "bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 2 ] },
              { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 3 ] }
          ] } );
  } );
  ```
- [DataTables server-side processing example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html):

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').dataTable( {
          "bProcessing": true,
          "bServerSide": true,
          "sAjaxSource": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
      } );
  } );
  ```

  where the response should look similarly to this:

  ```
  {
      "sEcho": 1,
      "iTotalRecords": "57",
      "iTotalDisplayRecords": "57",
      "aaData": [
          [
              "Gecko",
              "Netscape Navigator 9",
              "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
              "1.8",
              "A"
          ],
          [
              "Gecko",
              "Mozilla 1.0",
              "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
              "1",
              "A"
          ]
      ]
  }
  ```
- [DataTables with column rendering](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html):

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').dataTable( {
          "aoColumnDefs": [ 
              {
                  "fnRender": function ( oObj ) {
                      return oObj.aData[0] +' '+ oObj.aData[3];
                  },
                  "aTargets": [ 0 ]
              },
              { "bVisible": false,  "aTargets": [ 3 ] },
              { "sClass": "center", "aTargets": [ 4 ] }
          ]
      } );
  } );
  ```

Is it enough for an example of initialization code?

Comment: Links are not an answer. This would have been a good comment, though.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I have updated my answer and added the code from the linked pages. Seems to answer questions, unless OP will clarify what exactly he needs.

Comment: I have two field in table database (id,name), but i want datatable show static number column and name column with one hidden coloumn for field id. Thank for helping.

Comment: @IdhamPerdameian: Then use both examples I have given, and return static number within the result from the server. I guess it should help.

Comment: @Tadeck: Yes i use both, but return alert result said "DataTabels warning(tabel id ='example'): Requested unknown parameter '2' from the data source for row 0
I think it because i have three coloumn in DataTabel and server-site returning two field from table(id,name) in database.

Comment: @IdhamPerdameian: Ok, I have added the example showing how to render a column. I still think though, that the easiest solution is to provide this static number by the script from server (and generate it in a way that will suit your needs).